# "I changed into my sweats" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've been reading "W is for Wasted" book by Sue Grafton and have found the phrase meaning of which I am unable to find anywhere on the web.

> I **changed into my sweats** and put together a deluxe hot
>   hard-boiled-egg sandwich and poured myself a glass of Chardonnay.

Comment: "Sweatshirt" and "sweat pants".  A "hoodie" is a form of sweatshirt.

Answer (score 2):

It's a colloquial (primarily North American) term.

> informal term for sweatsuit or sweatpants.
>   denoting loose casual garments made of thick, fleecy cotton.
>
> "sweat tops and bottoms"

Comment: Generally worn for exercise, hence the 'sweat'.  Or at least historically intended to be so worn, though they've become common casual wear even among the non-exercising population.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, @jamesqf. It never occurred to me that OP might also not be aware of what they are/are for.

Comment: @Rathony Yeah, I'd better clean up mine too. :) Thanks for your help.